# PHP - IF Statement to compare / verify text

Tags: php, string, if-statement, text, comparison

Fairly new to PHP - But I come from a fairly fluent Classic ASP VBScript background.

PHP 5.5 (?) - Somewhere in there.
MySQL db.

- Have a MySQL table with a column [sale_status]
- [sale_status] has values of "E" or "P" ("Expired" or "Pending", respectively)
- I am looping through the table with PHP, and it displays all the values correctly ("E" or "P")
- I am trying to do an "IF Statement" to do something when the value is "E" and something other thing for anything else.
- My "IF Statement reads like...":

  ```
  $salestatus = {{sale_status}}

  if ($salestatus == "E") {
       echo ("YES");
  } ELSE {
       echo ("NO");
  }
  ```
- For this, I get `NO` for everything (`E` and `P`).
- I have tried `===` and `strcmp` and `strcasecmp`, but get the same thing.
- I KNOW the values from {{sale_status}} are correct, because I can just `echo` that variable through the loop, and it display all the correct values.
- For some reason, though, it will not distinguish `E` from `P`, or whatever.
- In Classic ASP, it would be as simple as (`if {sale_status} = "E"`, then ...) - and it works.
- I know PHP has its own nuances, so that is what I am trying to learn.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: try `$salestatus = trim({{sale_status}})` maybe there are some spaces in `sale_status`

Comment: Either that ^ and/or the way you're querying your DB.

Comment: As said by other comments you should check the contents of your $salestatus variable, for example using [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) and checking if its value is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.

-gellu:
I did try a TRIM, but appears to have same result.


@Nicolas Faure:
I did, indeed, do a var_dump, and here are the results:
***
array (size=2)
  'sale_status' => string 'P' (length=1)
  'sale_ID' => string '509' (length=3)
array (size=2)
  'sale_status' => string 'E' (length=1)
  'sale_ID' => string '510' (length=3)
array (size=2)
  'sale_status' => string 'E' (length=1)
  'sale_ID' => string '511' (length=3)

... etc.
***

I only have one record (The first one) as "P", for testing.
The others are "E".

Seems like the value is fine.